# Is there an escape character in MASM?

Tags: assembly, escaping, masm, masm32

I know that strings surrounded by single quotes can contain double quotes and vice versa, but can a string contain both? For example, the string:

```
How do you say, "Where's the bathroom?" in Spanish?
```

Answer (score 5):

It's been a very long time and a quick google search wasn't helpful.

```
"How do you say, ""Where's the bathroom?"" in Spanish?"
```

Double quotes work.

Answer (score -1):

A backslash character should work to escape an embeded quote or apostrophe, e.g. \"

Comment: Not for MASM. `error A2109: only white space or comment can follow backslash`